# Why bootstrap cols break to new line in print view?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">50%</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">50%</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33.33%</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:orange;">33.33%</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33.33%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On bigger screen you can see 2 and 3 columns respectively but in print view why every col is in new line ?

Answer (score 0):

because Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content. It’s built with a flexbox and is fully responsive.

Comment: But how can I make it looks the same in print view?

Comment: you can't make the same width in all devices, and because of that, the elements show different.